# Reference a scalar property from a string value

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I have a `combobox` that contains a list of scalar properties of an `entity`. I need to do a search on the property specified by the user in the `combobox`.

How do I reference the property when I have it as a string?

Something similar to `DBSet<>` for entity.

Example:

```
if (order.Firstname != null && order.Firstname.ToLower().Contains(textBoxSearch.Text.ToLower()))
```

In the above example, I need to replace `Firstname` with `Surname` or any other property, at runtime, depending on what the user selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx), for your case you'll need something along these lines:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var entity = new Entity {
            Height = 172,
            FirstName = "Foo",
            Birthday = new DateTime(1, 1, 1995)
        };

        var firstName = GetEntityProperty<string>(entity, "FirstName");
    }

    public static T GetEntityProperty<T>(object entity, string propertyName)
    {
        var type = entity.GetType();
        var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);

        return (T)property.GetValue(entity);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided solution works, but it is not strongly-typed, so it is sensible to property renaming. A strongly-typed approach can be used, but it requires some setup. However, part of the setup is so generic that it can be reused:

```
public class Order
{
    public String OrderNo { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String Misc { get; set; }
}   

// clearly define properties that allow search
public enum OrderSearchableProp
{
    OrderNo = 1,
    FirstName = 2,
    LastName = 3
}

class Program
{
    // strongly-type requires an explicit mapping between property and its expression within the order object
    static Dictionary<OrderSearchableProp, Expression<Func<Order, String>>> OrderSearchableMap = new Dictionary<OrderSearchableProp, Expression<Func<Order, string>>>()
    {
        { OrderSearchableProp.OrderNo, o => o.OrderNo },
        { OrderSearchableProp.FirstName, o => o.FirstName },
        { OrderSearchableProp.LastName, o => o.LastName },
    };

    // this gets a PropertyInfo based from an Expression. It should be placed into a generic utility class 
    // credit goes to Daniel - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17116267/2780791
    public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyFromExpression<T, TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> GetPropertyLambda)
    {
        MemberExpression Exp = null;

        //this line is necessary, because sometimes the expression comes in as Convert(originalexpression)
        if (GetPropertyLambda.Body is UnaryExpression)
        {
            var UnExp = (UnaryExpression)GetPropertyLambda.Body;
            if (UnExp.Operand is MemberExpression)
            {
                Exp = (MemberExpression)UnExp.Operand;
            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        else if (GetPropertyLambda.Body is MemberExpression)
        {
            Exp = (MemberExpression)GetPropertyLambda.Body;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        return (PropertyInfo)Exp.Member;
    }

    public static IList<Order> getFilteredOrders(int propFilterValue, IList<Order> orders, String needle)
    {
        var filterValue = (OrderSearchableProp)propFilterValue;
        var filterProp = OrderSearchableMap[filterValue];
        var lowNeedle = needle?.ToLower() ?? String.Empty;

        return orders.Where(o =>
            {
                var propInfo = GetPropertyFromExpression<Order, String>(filterProp);
                var propValue = (String) propInfo.GetValue(o) ?? String.Empty;
                return propValue.ToLower().Contains(lowNeedle);
            }).ToList();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // can be used to populate the combo items
        // otherwise, not used in this example
        OrderSearchableProp[] enumValues = (OrderSearchableProp[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(OrderSearchableProp));

        // test orders
        var orderList = new List<Order>()
            {
                new Order() { OrderNo = "1234ABC", FirstName = "George", LastName = "Taylor", Misc = "Extra information"},
                new Order() { OrderNo = "AB10", FirstName = "Anonymous", LastName = "X", Misc = "No comment"}
            };

        // test OrderNo search
        var searchProp = (int) OrderSearchableProp.OrderNo;
        var foundOrders = getFilteredOrders(searchProp, orderList, "ABC");

        // test FirstName search
        searchProp = (int)OrderSearchableProp.FirstName;
        foundOrders = getFilteredOrders(searchProp, orderList, "a");

        // test LastName search with empty string
        searchProp = (int)OrderSearchableProp.LastName;
        foundOrders = getFilteredOrders(searchProp, orderList, "");

        // empty return
        searchProp = (int)OrderSearchableProp.OrderNo;
        foundOrders = getFilteredOrders(searchProp, orderList, null);

    }
}
```