# Enforce that `Expression<Func<TInstance,TProp>>` has a Body that is a `MemberExpression`

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, expression

```
public void GiveMeAProp(Expression<Func<TInstance,TProp>> prop)
```

Is often used as the standard way of saying "please give me a property selector". But there are many things that can satisfy this signature but not actually be the "real" property. e.g. All of the following compile.

```
GiveMeAProp(x => Method());
GiveMeAProp((x) => localVariable);
GiveMeAProp(x => x);
GiveMeAProp(x => (Type)x);
GiveMeAProp((x) => !x.BooleanProp);
```

I certainly could simply declare that my method takes a `MemberExpression`, but then I lose the strict typing of my expression, and in particular lose the ability to write:

```
public void SetThisProp(Expression<Func<TInstance,TProp>> prop, TProp value)
```

I can have a run time check that the expression I've ended up with has a Body that is a `MemberExpression`, but it would be really nice if I could have the type system enforce that for me? No other kind of `Expression<T>` is actually a valid argument in my use-case.

**Question: Is there anyway that I can enforce *statically* that an argument represents a `MemberExpression` and *also* that it returns a type `T`?**

Comment: No, there is not. However, using an expression as a property selector is less common now that `nameof` has been introduced.

Comment: If you want a `MemberExpression` then why not require that instead of `Expression<>`?

Comment: @DavidG I've literally answered that *exact* question, in my question. It's the 3rd sentence!?

Comment: But then you are limited to doing this at runtime. You may be able to write a static Roslyn analyser, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway that I can enforce statically that an argument represents a MemberExpression and also that it returns a type T?

No, not at present in C#.

It is difficult to prove a negative, but I think it is reasonably clear from all the various libraries which follow the pattern you cite that this is the optimal approach here. If there were a better approach, I think it would have caught on pretty widely by now.

For example, the ["`OrderBy`" method in Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Queryable_OrderBy__2_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___) is a pretty classic example of a library asking for a property in a typesafe way, as you are doing here, and they haven't managed to avoid the same pitfalls you cite:

```
public static System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource,TKey> (this System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource> source, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>> keySelector);

var studentsOrderByRank = students.OrderBy(w => w.Rank);
```

The following will compile, but fail at runtime:

```
string localVar = "example";
var studentsOrderByRank = students.OrderBy(w => localVar);
```

I think that, so long as your library gives clear error messages at runtime if users pass a `Expression<Func<TInstance,TProp>>` which is not in fact a property access, this is the best you can do.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54610913/8261) for best practices in your library re consuming these expressions.